# Laravel Eloquent - Query where secondValue if no results with initialValue

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, query-builder

I have a model named `Document`, `Document` has a status field where the possible values are, let's say dummy_data `['done', 'failed', 'sent', ....]`.

I want to get all documents `where status='done'` if they are present in DB OR all documents where `status='sent'` if first condition is `false`.

I have tried this query but I get documents with both statuses.

```
$result->documents()->where(function ($query) {
                $query->where('status', 'done')
                    ->orWhere('status', 'sent');
            })->get();
```

Comment: You'll need to separate it out into 2 different queries, I believe. Check for documents that are `done`. Then if there are no results, run another query for `sent`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is no problem, you can split into two queries. The code will also be easier to read.

```
// getting documents with status done
$documentsQuery = $result->documents()->where('status','done');
 

// if there are no documents, add the other condition
if(!$documentsQuery->exists()){
    $documentsQuery = $documentsQuery->orWhere('status','sent');
}

dd($documentsQuery->get());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `orWhereRaw` and do raw query for `OR` which check if first where has no result.

```
$result->documents()->where('status', 'done')
    // OR clause which checks if first where has no result
    ->orWhereRaw("status = 'sent' AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM documents WHERE status = 'done')") 
    ->get();
```

it should have the same query as below where the `OR` has additional subquery for checking the existence of the first where

```
WHERE (
    status = 'done' 
    OR status = 'sent' AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM documents WHERE status = 'done')
);
```

Comment: I would put that as separate `where()` and `whereSub()` statements inside a `where()` closure to keep raw use to a minimum and get the explicit parentheses in the query but +1 this is the correct approach

Answer (score 0):

You can query in two steps, first query documents with `status=done`.
If the documents cannot be found, then query the documents with `status=sent`.

```php
$documents = $result->documents()
                    ->where('status', 'done')
                    ->get();

if ($documents->count() === 0) {
    $documents = $result->documents()
                        ->where('status', 'sent')
                        ->get();
}
```

Alternatively, you can also complete it in the same query, but the performance of this query method is poor (`not recommended`).

```php
$documents = $result->documents()
                    ->where(function ($query) {
                        $query->where('status', 'done')
                              ->orWhere(function ($query) {
                                  $query->where('status', 'sent')
                                        ->whereNotExists(function ($query) {
                                            $query->from('documents')
                                                  ->where('documents.status', 'done');
                                        });
                              });
                    })
                    ->get();
```